# What determines what chat rooms show up at chat.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, chat

Whenever I go to the chat 'homepage' (https://chat.stackexchange.com/), it always is on the EE.SE site.  Why is this?  Can I change it to a different site?

Comment: You must be on the starred tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at https://chat.stackexchange.com/, I see this page:

[image: screenshot]

It seems the page remembers which tab I select, because if I select the "favorite" tab, go to another site, and then return to https://chat.stackexchange.com/, this is what I see.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Guess that works to get away from the site-only rooms, but even when I change it and return to the page, it goes back to what it was before